# How to rotate WCSsubplot 90 degrees in matplotlib

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, matplotlib

I want to rotate my WCSsubplot 90 degrees clockwise, I'm doing this for a scatter plot and an ax.imshow. I have been able to get the proper orientation for the ax.imshow by doing:
`img_rotate = np.rot90(cutout_j.data)`
`ax.imshow(img_rotate, cmap='Greys', norm=norm1_w1)`
But I have not figured it out for the scatter plot, I have tried rotating the matrix, converting it to pixels and rotating it, and using rotate = 90 to redefine the was but it does not work sadly.

Here is my current code:

````
           # Sets the WCS coordinates for the plots
            ax = plt.subplot(projection = wcs_cropped)

            # Apply the rotation to the object positions and plot them
            circle_size = (radius*3)
            scatter = plt.scatter(object_ra, object_dec, s = circle_size, edgecolor = '#40E842', facecolor = 'none')

            # Normalize the image and plots it
            init_top, init_bot = 95, 45
            norm1_w1 = matplotlib.colors.Normalize(vmin=np.nanpercentile(total_data.data, init_bot), vmax=np.nanpercentile(total_data.data, init_top))
            img_rotate = np.rot90(cutout_j.data)
            ax.imshow(img_rotate, cmap='Greys', norm=norm1_w1)```
````